# Cloudflare cache image downloads

Tags: amazon-aws, cloudflare

Is there a way to have cloudflare cache image downloads, ( content type application/octet-stream, Content-Disposition attachment )? Images are hosted on AWS S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the files using cache-headers on the container of your files on the S3.

Simply change the TTLS and this will start caching the files: check out [Automatically apply HTTP Headers](http://s3browser.com/automatically-apply-http-headers.php).

Comment: Thanks, sadly I have a million files already up there, 305,000 in 4 sizes. Looks like I have to run a script to set the expired header

Comment: Shouldn't need to use lots of containers, you should be using folders within the containers.